# Why is this code giving me an error?

Tags: android

The following code gave me an error

```
public class SuperImage3Activity extends Activity 
{

    ImageView image1, image2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.sourceimage1); // error here

        image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.sourceimage2); // error here

    }
```

I indeed created a directory named drawable and placed sourceimage1.jpg and sourceimage2.jpg in the directory.

the recommendation given by Eclipse is,

"As of ADT 14, the resource fields (such as doraemon) are no longer constants when defined in library objects.
This is necessary to make library projects resuable without recompiling them.

One consequence of this is that you can no longer use the fields directinly in switch statements.
You must use an if-else chain instead
"

Answer (score 2):

```
R.id.imageview1
R.id.imageview2
```

You have made Xml layout in res/layout from there you link your widgets or views or any other control or you can make your control dynamically. like this

```
ImageView imageView1=new ImageView(this);
imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.sourceimage1);
```

Comment: findViewyId means the Control Id in XML LAYOUT so there you have to give the id of the control rather than its iamge resource. Thanks

Comment: http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/                                                                     You can take a look at this example

Comment: Rather than comment on your own answer, consider modifying the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` is used to find a view **that is already part** of the view you're calling the method on (usually an activity).

Basically the way it's done is: (in order)

1. First you design a layout (either in a XML layout file, or programmatically) which lists all your components and desired locations.
2. You allocate an id to the resource you're interested in (either using `android:id="@+id/your_id_here"` in your XML, or `setId(XX)` if your layout is done programmatically)
3. You set this layout to your activity or as a child of an existing component (usually with `setContentView`)
4. Now you can use `findViewById` using the identifier defined in 2.

`findViewById` is **not** used with a resource itself as a parameter (your drawable object).